# React - pass array values from arrow function to another .js file

Tags: arrays, reactjs, arrow-functions

I'm pretty new to React and development at all, so please don't mind this "easy" question.

I have one file "CreateRandomArray.js" which will fill an array with random numbers under 10 and checks if this number already exists.

```
import React from 'react';

const createRandomArray = () => {

const array = [];
let indexer = 0;

do {
    let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*30)
    if ( randomnumber < 10){
        let result = array.includes(randomnumber)
        console.log(result)
        if (!result) {
            array[indexer] = randomnumber
            indexer = indexer + 1
        } null
    } null
 } while (indexer < 10)
}

export default createRandomArray
```

Now I would love to use this array in another file but I can't find a way to get access to the value in this array. I already did several versions with "return" but it never worked.

So, does anyone knows how I can make use of this array in another .js file and assign those values for example to another array?

Thank you :)

ps: If you could explain it like you would explain it to an ape, it would be much appreciated ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your feedback. With the help of a colleague, I found a different solution which is a little embarrassing to post, because of its simplicity :)

This is the file which generates my random array and where I added "return array":

```
import React from 'react';

const createRandomArray = () => {

const array = [];
let indexer = 0;

do {
    let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*30)
    if ( randomnumber < 10){
        let result = array.includes(randomnumber)
        console.log(result)
        if (!result) {
            array[indexer] = randomnumber
            indexer = indexer + 1
        } null
    } null
} while (indexer < 10)

return array
}

export default createRandomArray;
```

In my App.js file, I import the other one and set my variable equal to the function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CreateRandomArray from './CreateRandomArray';

class app extends Component {

whatever = CreateRandomArray();


render() {  

    return (
        <div>{this.whatever}</div>
    )

  }
}

export default app
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```js
const getRandomArray = (size, max) => {

  const array = [];
  let index = 0;

  for(index = 0; index < size; index ++) {
    let rand = 0;
    do {
      rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    } while (array.some((value) => value === rand )) // check array values
    array.push(rand); // then push
  }

  return array;
}

export default getRandomArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import the array, to do it so, import it on the file you wish by pasting the following code on the top:

```js
import {createRandomArray} from './createRandomArrayFile'
```

Where **createRandomArrayFile** is the name of the .js file stored, you do not need to put the extension, although you can.

You can call it now as `{createRandomArray}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `CreateRandomArray` function from the file in another component. You can do it like so.

**ParentComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import CreateRandomArray from './CreateRandomArray.js`

const ParentComponent = (props)=> {

  const doSomethingWithArray = (CreateRandomArray)=>{
     var arrayValues = CreateRandomArray();
     //do something with arrayValues 
  }

  return (<div>{doSomethingWithArray(CreateRandomArray)</div>}

}
```

And you will need a return value within `CreateRandomArray.js`

**CreateRandomArray.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const createRandomArray = () => {

const array = [];
let indexer = 0;

do {
    let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*30)
    if ( randomnumber < 10){
        let result = array.includes(randomnumber)
        console.log(result)
        if (!result) {
            array[indexer] = randomnumber
            indexer = indexer + 1
        } null
    } null
 } while (indexer < 10)
  return array
}

export default createRandomArray;
```